# react native react-native-sqlite-storage not working

Tags: database, sqlite, react-native

I use react native react-native-sqlite-storage in my project and I create 2 tables, but in a select query, this code doesn't print anything.

```
import {openDatabase} from "react-native-sqlite-storage";
.
.
.

export function selectAllData() {
    const db = openDatabase({name: 'myDb.db'});
    db.transaction(function (txn) {
        txn.executeSql('SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME', [], (tx, results) => {
            let len = results.rows.length;
            console.log('len', len);
            for(let i = 0; i < len; i++)
                console.log(results.rows.item(i));
        });
    })
}
```

I expect this code prints all rows of the table but nothing prints.

Comment: Is this for android or iOs? I am asking because you will need to link in some cases. Also, the code you have added is not enough for me to try and give valuable input. Based on what I see now, shouldn't you open your database by this command: `SQLite.openDatabase()` ?

Comment: I use android. openDatabase is imported here.

Comment: Did you pre-create the DB?

Comment: yes, I created the DB and tables and inserted rows.

Answer (score -2):

**Try this**

```js
db.transaction(tx => {
  tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME', [], (tx, results) => {
    var temp = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < results.rows.length; ++i) {
      temp.push(results.rows.item(i));
    }
    console.log('TABLE_NAME', temp)

  });
});
```

Comment: When possible, please make an effort to provide additional explanation instead of just code. Such answers tend to be more useful as they help members of the community and especially new developers better understand the reasoning of the solution, and can help prevent the need to address follow-up questions.

Comment: i have also some issue with the sqlite in react native, can u help me please ?